# Update text field based on selection in drop-down list(Angular JS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a drop-down list using angular-Js.
The element that is coming should be currently selected in drop-down list is coming from some databse.(Initialized as $scope.choice = "two", in sample app).

With the below code, last element in the list is the sleected element alwyas.
Also, in the associated text box, I want the description to change based on the selected element, but it always defaults to the description of the first item in list box.

JS File

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('Test',function($scope)
{
    $scope.choice = "two";
    $scope.items = [{name: 'one', age: 30, description: 'Thirty' },{ name: 'two', age: 27, description: 'Twenty Seven' },{ name: 'three', age: 50, description: 'Fifty' }];
});
```

HTML

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="Test">

     <table class="table table-striped">

       <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><select
                        ng-model="selectedItem"
                            ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.name" ></select></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="field" ng-model=" selectedItem.description"
                           class="form-control"ng-pattern="/{{ selectedItem.description}}/" required /></td>


            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I change the drop-down element in list, I get the following error:

```
    Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/$parse/syntax?p0=undefined&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=null&p3=%2F%2F&p4=%2F%2F
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:6:416
    at eb.throwError (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:190:268)
    at eb.primary (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:189:450)
    at eb.unary (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:196:183)
    at eb.multiplicative (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:195:486)
    at eb.additive (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:195:280)
    at eb.relational (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:195:144)
    at eb.equality (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:195:6)
    at eb.logicalAND (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:194:387) <input type="text" name="field" ng-model=" selectedItem.description" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-pattern="/{{ selectedItem.description}}/" required=""> angular.js:11383(anonymous function) angular.js:11383(anonymous function)
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That bit is reason of your error

```
ng-pattern="/{{ selectedItem.description}}/"
```

if you want choose default option you can do that by:

```
 $scope.items = [{name: 'one', age: 30, description: 'Thirty' },{ name: 'two', age: 27, description: 'Twenty Seven' },{ name: 'three', age: 50, description: 'Fifty' }];

 //set default option      
 $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[1]
```

---

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {



  $scope.items = [{
    name: 'one',
    age: 30,
    description: 'Thirty'
  }, {
    name: 'two',
    age: 27,
    description: 'Twenty Seven'
  }, {
    name: 'three',
    age: 50,
    description: 'Fifty'
  }];

  $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[1]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <table class="table table-striped">

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.name"></select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="field" ng-model=" selectedItem.description" class="form-control" ng-pattern="" required />
          </td>


        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```